# Android process hangs while reading data from select

Tags: java, android, runtime

i have the following code snippet:

```
..
..
..
Process proc = runTimeObject.exec(new String[]{"su"});
        System.out.println("0");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
        //String Sql = "sqlite3 -csv /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db \"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE status<>13 AND key_from_me=0;\" > /data/test.csv";
        String Sql = "sqlite3 -csv /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db \"SELECT m._id, m.key_remote_jid, m.data, m.media_wa_type, m.media_name FROM messages m, chat_list cl WHERE m.key_remote_jid = cl.key_remote_jid AND m.key_from_me=0 AND cl.unseen_message_count>0 AND m._id>COALESCE(cl.last_read_message_table_id, 0);\"";
        System.out.println("1");
        if (outputStream != null){
            System.out.println("2");
            outputStream.writeBytes(Sql);
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("3");
            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println("4");
            }
            System.out.println("5");
        }
        System.out.println("6");
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

the while loop shows all selected data but the program hangs hier and does not go forward(i do not see the 5). I am new in java and Android and do not know how i solve this problem. please help me

Comment: can you see infinite 4's?

Comment: Are you sure your inputstream as an end ?

Comment: thank you for all answers. I see so much 4's as the selected data and this is true(29 selected data und 29 4's). How can i proof that my inputstream has an end. The loop reads all the input and show it, therefor i suppose my inputstream has an end. I have just tried to read the errorstream(before the inputstream) it says there is an error near 'exit' and it hangs here, it does not go forward to read the inputstream. And when i remove the 'exit' it hangs after the first flush.  Any idea

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a long running task on the main thread? If you block the main thread for more than a few milliseconds your application will be terminated.
Try running the task in the background by using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: thank you for the answer. No my task does select and shows the selected data on the screen. That is all. Is there a better way how i read data from a databank, but i need su

Comment: That sounds like a long running task to me - a long running task is anything that takes more than a second or two in the Android world. I would run that task in the background.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i have forgott the '\n' at the end of the select command.